# Pad a dataframe with pane data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing

I have a dataframe like this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'User':['A','A','A','A','B', 'B'], 
                   'Month':['2017-01-01','2017-03-01','2017-05-01','2017-09-01','2017-01-01','2017-05-01'],
                    'count':[2,2,2,2,5,5]})
```

I want to pad the data so that it looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'User':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
               'Month':['2017-01-01','2017-02-01','2017-03-01','2017-04-01','2017-05-01','2017-06-01','2017-07-01','2017-08-01','2017-09-01','2017-10-01','2017-11-01','2017-12-01','2017-01-01','2017-02-01','2017-03-01','2017-04-01','2017-05-01','2017-06-01','2017-07-01','2017-08-01','2017-09-01','2017-10-01','2017-11-01','2017-12-01'], 
               'count':[2,0,2,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
    df.User.unique(),
    pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods=12, freq='MS')
], names=['User', 'Month'])

df.set_index(['User', 'Month']).reindex(mux, fill_value=0) \
  .swaplevel(0, 1).reset_index()

        Month User  count
0  2017-01-01    A      2
1  2017-02-01    A      0
2  2017-03-01    A      2
3  2017-04-01    A      0
4  2017-05-01    A      2
5  2017-06-01    A      0
6  2017-07-01    A      0
7  2017-08-01    A      0
8  2017-09-01    A      2
9  2017-10-01    A      0
10 2017-11-01    A      0
11 2017-12-01    A      0
12 2017-01-01    B      5
13 2017-02-01    B      0
14 2017-03-01    B      0
15 2017-04-01    B      0
16 2017-05-01    B      5
17 2017-06-01    B      0
18 2017-07-01    B      0
19 2017-08-01    B      0
20 2017-09-01    B      0
21 2017-10-01    B      0
22 2017-11-01    B      0
23 2017-12-01    B      0
```

Comment: Pretty close! Thanks for the quick response. The user column must be A and B's, no zeroes.

Comment: And feel free change your answer for not showing me under your answer ;)

Comment: Sure, I know ;)

Comment: `swaplevel` can be chopped right? I'm guessing you're using it for column order?

Comment: @Zero I put it there just to get the columns in right order.  Yes, it could be gotten rid of.

Answer (score 4):

Use `set_index`, `unstack` and `reindex`

```
In [591]: tidx = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods=12, freq='MS')

In [592]: (df.set_index(['Month', 'User'])['count'].unstack()
             .reindex(tidx)
             .fillna(0)
             .unstack().reset_index()
             .rename(columns={'level_1': 'Month', 0: 'count'}))
Out[592]:
   User      Month  count
0     A 2017-01-01    2.0
1     A 2017-02-01    0.0
2     A 2017-03-01    2.0
3     A 2017-04-01    0.0
4     A 2017-05-01    2.0
5     A 2017-06-01    0.0
6     A 2017-07-01    0.0
7     A 2017-08-01    0.0
8     A 2017-09-01    2.0
9     A 2017-10-01    0.0
10    A 2017-11-01    0.0
11    A 2017-12-01    0.0
12    B 2017-01-01    5.0
13    B 2017-02-01    0.0
14    B 2017-03-01    0.0
15    B 2017-04-01    0.0
16    B 2017-05-01    5.0
17    B 2017-06-01    0.0
18    B 2017-07-01    0.0
19    B 2017-08-01    0.0
20    B 2017-09-01    0.0
21    B 2017-10-01    0.0
22    B 2017-11-01    0.0
23    B 2017-12-01    0.0
```

Comment: That still leaves older nans from unstack, hence doing it later.